# What is the value of my Bézier curve (with known control points), at $t = \frac12$?

Tags: graphing-functions, bezier-curve

A Bézier curve $Q$ has control points $P_0 = (0,0,0)$, $P_1 = (0,1,0)$, $P_2 = (1,1,0)$ and $P_3 = (2,0,0)$. What point is $Q(\frac12)$?

Answer (score 4):

The equation of the Bézier curve is 
$$
Q(t) = (1-t)^3P_0 + 3t(1-t)^2P_1 + 3t^2(1-t)P_2 + t^3P_3
$$
Setting $t=\tfrac12$ gives
$$
Q(\tfrac12) = \tfrac18 P_0 + \tfrac38 P_1 + \tfrac38 P_2 + \tfrac18 P_3 
$$
Then substitute your known control points.